# Python - give wrapper function the same name as wrapped function

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

Is it possible to modify the decorator function

```
def wrap(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(function.__name__)
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

to make the code

```
@wrap
@wrap
@wrap
def hello():
    print("Hello, world!")


hello()
```

print

```
hello
hello
hello
Hello, world!
```

instead of

```
wrapper
wrapper
hello
Hello, world!
```

? My aim is to compose several decorators that all rely on the function name.

Comment: functools.update_wrapper? functools

Comment: functools.wraps?

Comment: Thanks, that works! Do you want to post an answer? If not, I'll edit the question to include your solution.

Comment: @Rastapopoulus Can't do much currently. I'm at an airport and about to board

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work, although I am not quite sure of your intent.

Anyway, trusting my guts, I would eschew such constructions.

```
import functools

def wrap(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(function.__name__)
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@wrap
@wrap
@wrap
def hello():
    print("Hello, world!")

hello()
```